# How to add a character to the beginging of each string in a list of strings

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a simple list of strings and what i need to do is to add "@" to the beginning of each item and  join the list to get something like: "@item1, @item2,...."

my code so far:

```
    Dim list As New List(Of String)({"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"})

    ' create a copy of list to prevent altering it
    Dim listCopy As List(Of String) = list

    For i As Integer = 0 To listCopy.Count - 1
        list(i) = "@" & listCopy(i)
    Next

    Dim result As String = String.Join(", ", list.ToArray())
```

While this does the job but i feel that it's too much code for a simple function, the same thing can be done in python or javascript much easier like:

python:

```
copyList = [("@" + x) for x in list]
```

javascript:

```
copylist = list.map(function(x){return '@' + x})
```

Is there a similar function in vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [LINQ Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx)  to achieve this:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)({"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"})
dim list1 = list.Select(function (i) "@" + i)
for each item in list1
    Console.WriteLine(item)
next item
```

And the output is:

```
@item1
@item2
@item3
@item4
```

The result is an [`IEnumerable (Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. If you want again a `List (Of String)` than use the [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
dim list1 = list.Select(function (i) "@" + i).ToList()
```

Comment: Glad that the answer helped. LINQ to Objects has a lot of functional goodies.

Answer (score 2):

Use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
Dim result = (From s In list Select "@" & s)
```

Comment: do i not need to define the type of result like: `Dim result As List(Of String)`?

Comment: Just to be clear, the result is `IEnumerable(Of String)`, and no you don't. Even with option strict on.